# How to properly import llama-index classes?

Tags: python, python-3.x, llama-index

Recently I making some PoCs using Llama Index.

I'm following the [documentation](https://gpt-index.readthedocs.io/en/latest/examples/query_engine/sub_question_query_engine.html) in order to use routing features for different indexes. I made two indexes and I want to use SubQueryEngine to route the query engines that I have created.

In the tutorial, we have the following example of imports:

```
from llama_index import GPTVectorStoreIndex, SimpleDirectoryReader
from llama_index.tools import QueryEngineTool, ToolMetadata
from llama_index.query_engine import SubQuestionQueryEngine
```

But when I run my example, I'm not able to import ToolMetadata neither SubQuestionQueryEngine. I got the following error:

```
ImportError: cannot import name 'SubQuestionQueryEngine' from 'llama_index.query_engine'
```

Does anybody know what possible can be the problem? The other imports work normaly and I was able to run examples using GPTVectorStoreIndex class.

I'm using Python 3.10.11

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please provide the version of llama-index that you are using.

A simple fix would be: `pip install -U llama-index`. I frequently encounter issues due to the continuous updates of the library. I would suggest updating it every day just to make sure you are using the latest version.